# What is the best method to close off the backend?

Tags: wp-admin, security

**The goal**: Completely remove the ability to access the WordPress backend on the production domain. Ex. return a 404 for http://example.com/wp-admin

**Purpose**: I don't want any possibility of WordPress' backend being accessed across the Internet. Instead, it will only be accessibly via VPN on an internal domain (i.e. http://example.internal/wp-admin. *This ensures that no one could ever brute force attack the login page.*

I could restrict logins to a given IP address, but I don't want to keep up with a list of IPs. I'd prefer to use the security my VPN already offers.

Consider that `wp-admin` still has to be accessible in some fashion because there could be resources that the frontend calls.

Are there any solutions beyond redirecting `wp-login.php` somewhere else?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you know the sub-net of your VPN you could restrict access to /wp-admin via .htaccess using standard Apache rules.

```
<Directory /var/www/wp-admin/>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from 192.168.1.0/24
  Allow from 127
</Directory>
```

Obviously you'd need to adjust the directory and IP address subnet to suit your needs.

To restrict access to a specific file:

```
<Files _FILE_.php>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>
```

Again you can use a sub-net mask to suit your VPN.